# Jasmine angular unit test length of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have some function like this

```
  updateParts(enviromentContainsAllParts: PartsContainsAllParts): Observable<boolean> {
    const enviroment = cloneDeep(this.enviroment);
    enviroment.containsAllPart = enviromentContainsAllParts.containsAllPart;
    for (let index = 0; index < enviromentContainsAllParts.parts.length; index++) {
      const currentPart = enviromentContainsAllParts.parts[index];
      enviroment.parts.push({
        size: currentPart.sizeOfEnviroment
      });
    }
    return of(true);
  }
```

When i am try to unit test this

```
it('should have change enviroment parts', () => {
  // GIVEN
  const enviroment = cloneDeep(fakeCurrentEnviroment);
  service.enviroment = enviroment;
  // WHEN
  service.updateParts(building).subscribe(data =>
    expect(data).toBeTruthy()
  );
  // THEN
});
```

I got error like this
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
Does anyone knows where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Mock enviromentContainsAllParts with test data...otherwise enviromentContainsAllParts.length witll be undefined

Comment: How to mock, any info?

Answer (score 0):

I bet `environmentContainsAllParts.parts` is undefined in `building`.

Try this:

```
it('should have change enviroment parts', (done) => { // add done here to let jasmine know when the test is done
  // GIVEN
  const mockEnvironmentContainsAllParts = {
    containsAllPart: {
      
    }
    parts: [] // mock this array however you want
  };
  const enviroment = cloneDeep(fakeCurrentEnviroment);
  service.enviroment = enviroment;
  // WHEN
  service.updateParts(mockEnvironmentContainsAllParts).subscribe(data => // pass the mock and not building
    expect(data).toBeTruthy();
    done(); // let jasmine know you're done and we ensured it went inside of this subscribe and did the assertion
  );
  // THEN
});
```